# Writing a test for a browser resize event. PhantomJS, Mocha, Chai & Sinon

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, mocha.js, sinon, chai

I've not done a lot of testing on events, mainly business logic & i'm trying to find examples of testing something like a browser resize event.

The code in question would be the following.

```
ui.resized = function(c, t) {
    var curr,
        prev;
    window.addEventListener('resize',
        function() {
            curr = ui.viewport();
            if ( prev && curr != prev ) {
                clearTimeout(t);
                t = setTimeout(c, 50);
            }
            prev = curr || prev;
    }, false);
    return c;
};
```

Any ideas around this or can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar to this in a directive that builds a chart.  I want the chart to be redrawn whenever the window is resized so that it scales appropriately.  The directive looks like this:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('ad.common')
    .directive('zxChart', chartDirective);

/** @ngInject */
function chartDirective($window, MyService) {

    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.id = attrs.id || 'default-id';
        scope.width = attrs.width || $window.innerWidth - ($window.innerWidth * 0.1);

        attrs.$set('id', scope.id);

        angular.element($window).bind('resize', function () {
            scope.width = attrs.width || $window.innerWidth - ($window.innerWidth * 0.1);
            MyService.whenWindowIsResized(element[0], scope.width);
        });

        scope.$watch('chartData', function () {
            MyService.drawChart(element[0], scope.width, scope.chartData);
        });
    }

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<div id="" class="my-chart"></div>',
        scope: {
            chartData: '=',
        },
        link: link
    };
}
```

})();

My testing is done in two parts, first of all I test that the binding happens correctly:

```
describe('Check binding to event', function () {
    var $scope,
        $compile,
        stubWindow;

    beforeEach(function () {
        module('ad.common', function ($provide) {               
            stubWindow = {
                addEventListener: sinonSandbox.stub()
            };

            $provide.value('$window', stubWindow);
        });

        inject(function ($injector) {
            $scope = $injector.get('$rootScope').$new();
            $compile = $injector.get('$compile');
        });
    });

    it('should have added a resize event listener to $window', function () {
        var element = angular.element('<zx-chart id="foo"></zx-chart>');

        $compile(element)($scope);
        $scope.$digest();

        stubWindow.addEventListener.should.have.been.calledOnce;
        stubWindow.addEventListener.should.have.been.calledWith("resize");
    });
});
```

Then I test that triggering a resize event results in a call to a method that I want triggered when the resize event fires:

```
describe('Check call to event', function () {
    var $scope,
        $compile,
        $window,
        stubMyService;

    beforeEach(function () {
        module('ad.common', function ($provide) {
            stubMyService = {
                whenWindowIsResized: sinonSandbox.stub(),
            };

            $provide.value('MyService', stubMyService);
        });

        inject(function ($injector) {
            $scope = $injector.get('$rootScope').$new();
            $compile = $injector.get('$compile');
            $window = $injector.get('$window');
        });
    });

    it('a resize event should trigger a call to MyService.whenWindowIsResized', function () {
        var element = angular.element('<zx-chart id="foo"></zx-chart>');

        $compile(element)($scope);
        $scope.$digest();

        stubMyService.whenWindowIsResized.should.not.have.been.called;

        angular.element($window).triggerHandler('resize');

        stubMyService.whenWindowIsResized.should.have.been.calledOnce;
});
```

You will of course need to extract the functionality in the resize call out, and put it in a service.  But in my mind that just makes it easier to test.